# rake db:schema:dump

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rake

$ rake db:schema:dump

rake aborted !
it says..
couldn't parse YAML at line 31 column 11
then gives a link to environment file in config folder

> environment.rb:5 in <'top (required)'>
>
> tasks: TOP => db:schema:dump =>environment

what i did was changed the database.yml's adapter from sqlite3 to mysql. installed the yaml_db gem, added the socket value to /tmp/mysql.sock (not sure what this is.. just copied from somewhere..nothing of this sort exists in my pc)

the environment.rb has

> "#Load the rails application
>
> require File.expand_path('../application', **FILE**)
>
> "# Initialize the rails application
>
> Cmsapp::Application.initialize!

the databse.yml

> development:
>     adapter: mysql
>     encoding: utf8
>     reconnect: false
>     database: simple_cms_development
>     pool: 5
>     username: simple_cms
>     password: vishesh
>     socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
>
> test:
>     adapter: mysql
>     encoding: utf8
>     reconnect: false
>     database: simple_cms_test
>     pool: 5
>     username: simple_cms
>     password: vishesh
>     socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
>
> production:
>       adapter: mysql
>     encoding: utf8
>     reconnect: false
>     database: simple_cms_production
>     pool: 5
>     username: simple_cms
>     password: vishesh
>     socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

Answer (score 0):

Have you included the mysql2 gem in your gemfile and re-bundled it? Also make sure the database.yml is properly indented.